# is there a significant advantage by using a slug for an article?

Tags: content-management-system, seo

I was just wondering in cms systems, with regards to seo and other stuff, is there an advantage by using article slugs in urls like `example.com/article/the-article-name` 
 versus using the article id such as `example.com/article/view/3`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** There is not a **significant** advantage but there is a **small** advantage.

It is generally agreed upon that keywords in a URL help "a little bit".

See this video where Google's Matt Cutts answers the question, [Does the position of keywords in the URL affect ranking?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=gRzMhlFZz9I). In it he says, *"it does help a little bit to have keywords in the url"*.

Comment: nice and simple. thanks!